# If $I,J,K$ are ideals of a ring $R$ and $I+J=J+K=K+I=R$ then $IJ+JK+KI=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have made some progress using the First Isomorphism theorem but would like your opinion on how this should be done

Comment: $$R \subseteq I+J \subseteq I+J+K \subseteq R$$ so all those are equal.

Comment: You changed the question making all answers invalid. Don't, please.

Comment: are you sure this holds with no further requirements? i can prove it when $I, J, K$ commute (that is, $IJ = JI$ etc.).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, I totally missed that part, R is a commutative ring with neutral.

Answer (score 1):

If $I + J = R$, then $ K \subset I + J$. Hence, $I + J + K = I + J = R$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty trivial.   Of course  $I+J+K\subset R$.  But $R= I+J\subset I+J+K$.